# Does $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{C}$ implies $|f|<\infty$ almost everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

I was reading notes on measure theory, and just want some clarifications.

1. If $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to [0,+\infty]$, is it allowed to have $f(x)=+\infty$? What does it mean? Because when I learned the function $1/x$, it is not defined at 0. Further more, what does it mean to assign $+\infty$ to function over an interval, e.g., $f(x)=+\infty$ for $x\in[0,1]$? Is this allowed? I ask these because somewhere in the notes it reads "$f$ is finite almost everywhere" and I wonder what is $f$ like if it is not.
2. If $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{C}$, why is "finiteness almost everywhere automatic"? Does it mean there is no such thing as "extended complex plane"?

Thank you for your help.

---

Update: The text reads as follow.

> Properties of the simple unsigned integral.
>
> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d\to[0,+\infty]$ be simple unsigned functions.
>
> ...
>
> (ii) (Finiteness) We have Simp$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)\,dx\lt\infty$ if and only if $f$ is finite almost everywhare and its support has finite measure.
>
> ...

Comment: What kind of function is $f$ supposed to be ? Continuous, measurable, integrable ?

Comment: @berni-waterman I don't think anything is assumed for $f$. I'm just asking the terms and notation.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding domains of the functions. Function $f(x)=\frac1x$ is not defined for $x=0$ but if we look at a measureable function $g:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\to [0,\infty]$, then $g[0,1]=\int_0^1f(x)dx=\infty$. $\mathcal{B}$ denotes a sigma Borel-algebra.

Comment: @REr Forget about $1/x$. That's something I come up with. I've update the post and include the text I'm confused about.